# Trying to pass data as an argument to the services file

Tags: angular

I tried to pass the data from my `recipe-details.component.ts` to `recipe.services.ts` but got an issue. It says

> Property 'ingredients' does not exist on type 'Recipe[]'

Below is the code I tried; even when I try to `console.log(this.displayed.ingredients)`, I get the error

recipe-detail.component.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <img src="{{displayed.imageurl}}" alt="{{displayed.name}}" 
             class="img-responsive" style="max-height:300px">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h1>{{displayed.name}} </h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="btn-group" appDropdown>
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" 
                    type="button">Manage Recipe <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#" (click)="onaddtoshopping()" 
                       style="cursor:pointer;">Shopping List</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Edit Recipe</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Delete Recipe</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        {{displayed.description}}
    </div>
</div>
```

{{i.name}} - {{i.amount}}

recipe-detail.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipeservice } from '../recipe.service';
import { Recipe } from 'src/app/shared/recipe.modal';

@Component({
selector: 'app-recipe-details',
templateUrl: './recipe-details.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./recipe-details.component.css']
})
export class RecipeDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
displayed:Recipe[]=[]
constructor(private reservice:Recipeservice) {
this.reservice.passed.subscribe((i)=>{
  this.displayed=i
  // console.log(this.displayed)

    })
 }


ngOnInit() {


 }
onaddtoshopping(){
// this.reservice.onshoppingadd(this.displayed.ingredients)
console.log(this.displayed.ingredients)
}

}
```

recipe.service.ts

```
import { Recipe, } from '../shared/recipe.modal';
import {EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Ingredient } from '../shared/ingredients.modal';
// import { Shoppingrecipe } from '../shopping/shopping.service';
// @Injectable()
export class Recipeservice{
recipes:Recipe[]=[
new Recipe('Tasty Schnitzel','A super tasty Tasty Schnitzel-just 
awesome', 

[
  new Ingredient('Meat',12),
  new Ingredient('French Fries',5)
]),
new Recipe('Big fat burger','What else you need to say ?',
[
new Ingredient('Buns',3),
  new Ingredient('Meat',7)
])
]
// constructor(private slservice:Shoppingrecipe){}
passed=new EventEmitter<Recipe>()
out=new EventEmitter<string>()
onshoppingadd(ingredient){
// this.slservice.addingre(ingredient)
}
}
```

recipe.modal.ts

```
export class Recipe{
name;
description;
imageurl;
ingredients;
constructor(name,desc,path,ingre){
    this.name=name;
    this.description=desc;
    this.imageurl=path;
    this.ingredients=ingre
}

}
```

ingredients.modal.ts

```
export class Ingredient{
name;
amount;

constructor(name,amount){
    this.name=name;
    this.amount=amount;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an array, so you should request an ingredient with the index

```
displayed:Recipe[]=[] // this is an array of recipes
```

What you're doing.

```
console.log(this.displayed.ingredients)
```

How you should request. You need to find the ingredient with passing an index mate.

```
console.log(this.displayed[0].ingredients)
```

Comment: @Ipradhap    even i see in console the result as ....description: "A super tasty Tasty Schnitzel-just awesome !"
imageurl: "https://st.depositphotos.com/1000605/5119/i/950/depositphotos_51195205-stock-photo-tasty-schnitzel.jpg"
ingredients: (2) [Ingredient, Ingredient]
name: "Tasty Schnitzel" still when i try to access as u said i get the error of....Cannot read property 'description' of undefined but the same works in html when i try to display  by {{displayed.description}}

Comment: can u share a screenshot of the console log your getting with the data as you mention above?

Comment: @Ipradhap Here is the link to screenshot https://ibb.co/7ypHXVG  This is the whole data being displayed ...Now on accessing the 'description' here gives me the error i told above

Comment: your this.displayed is an array mate.. so try to extract the data with an index. Try
console.log(this.displayed[0].ingredients)

Comment: @Ipradhap i tried this ,it gives the same error of Cannot read property 'ingredients' of undefined

Comment: @RatnabhKumarRai I believe you need create a sample project and recreate this issue for more help mate..

Answer (score 0):

You have a few mistakes.

Use model instead of modal in recipe.modal.ts

recipe.service.ts: //@Injectable() uncomment this line

In the recipe.service.ts you didn't provide an imageUrl

```
new Recipe(
    'Tasty Schnitzel',
    'A super tasty Tasty Schnitzel-just awesome',
    //here
    'https://www.daringgourmet.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Schnitzel-7_edited.jpg',
    [
        new Ingredient('Meat',12),
        new Ingredient('French Fries',5)
    ]),
```